# Can we use bounding box cropping to avoid shortcut learning (achieve explainable AI)?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, feature-extraction, explainable-ai

Deep neural networks sometime use *shortcut* features (pseudo correlation) to predict.

For example, in cat-dog classification, the network may use the background information (e.g. floor, grass) as a shortcut. In lung cancer classification, the network may use features beyond the lung region ([see Fig-2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12553-021-00609-8)).

Such behaviors make the prediction unreliable (and not explainable to human). Hence, in shortcut learning, people study various techniques to avoid shortcut features.

Here, my question is: **Why not we just use a detection model (e.g. FastRCNN) to first detect the object (e.g. cat/dog, cancer) from the image, then predict the label based on the cropped image (where the background is masked)?**

---

This naive method must have some problems, otherwise it is not necessary to develop shortcut learning/robust learning papers.

From this [post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11949/can-bounding-boxes-further-improve-the-performance-of-a-cnn-classifier), I find some possible answers:

- training two networks (detection, classification) is costly in time.
- the detection model may generate mistaken bounding box.

However, I feel these answers are more from a technical aspect. None of them points out the **intrinsic** problem of the naive method.

Any suggestion, reference paper, etc. are welcomed.

Comment: Well, to do so you need to be aware that the background is problematic: there could be some other kind of images for which is not easy to say which "high-level features" could cause a shortcut. Also the bounding-box may be imprecise and contain irrelevant information: to this end a segmentation mask may be better.